# how i implode two variables

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm working integration of Izotope.js into wordpress
in origiginal there should be such construction

```
<option value="some-value">some-name</option>
```

I make two DB requests:

```
 global $wpdb;
    $res = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s", '___author') );
    $val = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s", '___value') );
```

and gather them

```
$authors = wp_list_pluck( $res, 'meta_value' );
$values = wp_list_pluck( $val, 'meta_value' );
```

i only know how to display like this

```
echo '<option>' . implode('</option><option>', $authors) .'</option>';
```

what i need is to get $values as value of option

Comment: How is `$res` and `$val` connected? It looks like those lists could easily have a different amount of results because they're not binded to each other in any way. Could you show the output of `print_r($authors);` and `print_r($values);`?

Comment: yes, they are the results of metaboxes in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this.

```
$authors = [
  'Me',
  'You',
];

$values = [
  10,
  101
];

$data = array_combine($values, $authors);

foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
  echo '<option value=" . $key . ">' . $value .'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Make sure there are an equal amount of array entries in both of your arrays else it will give you an error.